# api.ts:209 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I give up on this error, been scratching my head for quite a while now(need to check for dandruff, moving on), I was following a react-firebase tutorial from "Web-dev Simplified" from youtube.
Context: Till this part only the singup feature has been added, after the implementation, I closed my machine. Next day when I started my localhost getting the following error;

*api.ts:209 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)*
[image]

[image]

Following is the index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Following is the app.js

```js
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Container
        className='d-flex align-items-center justiiify-content-center'
        style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
      >
        <div className='w-100' style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
          <SignUp />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Following is the firebase.js the file to initialize the firebase configuration;

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
};
export default app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And the following is the context.js;

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  const signUp = (email, password) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const auth = getAuth();

    const unSubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
      }
    });

    return unSubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signUp,
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}
```

And at last the SignUp component

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { Form, Card, Button, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";

const SignUp = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
  const { signUp } = useAuth();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      setError(`Passwords do not match`);
    } else {
      try {
        setError(``);
        setLoading(true);
        await signUp(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(`Failed to create an account!`);
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className='text-center mb-4'>Sign Up</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant='danger'>{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id='email'>
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type='email' ref={emailRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id='password'>
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type='password' ref={passwordRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id='password-confirm'>
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type='password' ref={passwordConfirmRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className='w-100' type='submit'>
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className='w-100 text-center mt-2'>
        Already have an account?
        {/* <Link to='/login'>Log In</Link> */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

And the dependencies if that helps;

```
"bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

For the full code here is the Git repository;
https://github.com/RitwikNandi/React-Firebase-Auth

Thank you in advance, for taking your time out of your schedule to help me out!
regards,
Ritwik